# Commutative rings as images of domains

Tags: ring-theory

It is well known that the quotient ring $R/I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal.

If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, is it always possible to find an integral domain $D$ and ideal $I \subset D$ such that $R \cong D/I$ ?

Comment: Take free $\mathbb Z$ algebra $\mathbb Z[R].$

Comment: @user52045: Won't the free $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra [be non-commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) ?

Comment: Free commutative algebra is just a polynomial ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ be commutative ring and $X$ any set. Polynomial algebra $S[X]$ has following universal property. For any commutative S algebra A and map $f:X\rightarrow A$ there is unique homomorphism $\bar f:S[X] \rightarrow A$ such that $\bar f|_X=f$.

Now we can look at arbitrary commutative ring $R$ as $\mathbb Z$ algebra and take a map $id_R$. From universal property we get epimorphism $Z[R]\rightarrow R$. By isomorphism theorem we get what we want.